# Getting PostgreSQL function output in single call

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I have a PostgreSQL function which has a ref cursor as output parameter;

I know i can get output using below set of commands

```
begin;
select uspfillactions();
fetch All in "<unnamed portal 1>";
rollback;
```

But just want to know is there any way to get function output using single query?
Any dynamic query solution or anything else?

I don't want to mention `Begin` and `rollback/commit` also.

Comment: Change the function to `returns table(...)`  instead of a using refcursor

Comment: I Know this work around. I don't want to return the table.

Comment: Apparently you do, otherwise you wouldn't use `fetch all` (btw: some clients can do that automatically for you)